# How to wait till a server goes online to access a REST API

Tags: java, rest, ssl, port

I am trying to run a javaagent in a server, at it's start up. My agent will add a method call which is used to publish data to the same server. But before i publish the data, i need to modify specific value of the server using server's REST API. In that case, um trying to make GET and POST request to server's ssl port using following method.

```
public static String getCurrentSchema(String connectionUrl, String username, String password)
            throws IOException {
        String currentSchema = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(connectionUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            String authString = username + ":" + password;
            String authStringEnc = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes()));
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));
            currentSchema = br.readLine();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return currentSchema;
    }
```

When i start the server, instrumentation goes fine without any exceptions. but when the rest of the server start loading i am getting following exception, which i assume my publisher method is being called and it is trying to use the REST API, where it hasn't started yet.

Is there any way we can keep listening to that port till it becomes available and then do the REST call. Or are there any better way to do that. I would like to have some suggestions please.... I just can't figure out what to search in order to make this work.

Exception,

```
[2015-11-13 10:07:29,806] ERROR {org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to ssl://10.100.4.137:7711
org.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://10.100.4.137:7711
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
    at org.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to 10.100.4.137 on port 7711
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:407)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:208)
    ... 11 more
```

Once the server finish starting, i get following exception repeatedly. Could that be as a result of the above exception? What should i do to work around it. Some help please...!!

```
[2015-11-13 10:46:42,207]  INFO {org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup} -  No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec
[2015-11-13 10:46:42,212] ERROR {org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Could not initialize class org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:210)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    at org.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-11-13 10:46:42,214] ERROR {org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.100.4.137:7711
org.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.100.4.137:7711
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:210)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    at org.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: For the first problem, rewrite your logic to try again after some period of time if you get a connection refused exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to wait for the port,

```
boolean check=true;
while(check) {
    Socket s = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket(host, port);
        check=false;
    } catch(ConnectionException e) {
        System.out.println("trying again...");
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);// waiting 2 seconds before next try
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
        }
    } finally {
        if(s != null) {
            try {
                s.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add logs in exception as necessary.

Comment: Probably ConnectException instead of ConnectionException?